# The regular representation of finite group is always reducible.

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

I have to prove that the regular representation of a finite group is always reducible. This is equivalent to saying that the G invariant subspaces of it is the trivial subspace and the full subspace.I cant seem to do it. All i know is that the regular representation is a permutation matrix.

Comment: You seem to have confused reducibility with irreducibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, you should be showing that there is a $G$-invariant subspace which is not the trivial subspace or the full one.

There are some obvious ways to come up with $G$-invariant subspaces that aren't trivial or full for the regular representation. The representation is a permutation, so choosing something symmetric in the group will work. The span of $g_1 + g_2 +... + g_n$. will be invariant for example.

This shows that the representation is reducible. Finding the full decomposition of the representation is even more work!

Comment: what do you mean by the span of g1 + g2 + ........gn?

Comment: This does of course (as it has to) assume hat the group itself is not trivial.

Comment: I mean the sum of all elements of the group in the group ring. $\sum_{g \in G} g$.

Comment: @Harunrashid It might help if you include the way you have had the regular representation defined (there are several different ways to do this).

Comment: (For the $\phi : G \rightarrow V$ way, this would be the sum  $\sum_{g \in G} \phi(g)$)